# Join Multiple table without using joins

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two tables like

```
StudPersonalinfo
-----------------
studid,studname,father name,address,state,city,ExtraCurricularActivities
```

and another table is

```
Mark  
------------------
studid,studname,m1,m2,m3
```

Is there any other way to join these two tables without using join conditions?
Can anyone please help me..

Comment: hi, i suggest SQL view

Comment: how to write a query.

Comment: How about using `WHERE` clause? See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this Sql View

step 1 create view with join

```
CREATE VIEW StudentDetails
As
SELECT 
    t1.studID, 
    t2.studName,  
    t2.Mark1, 
    t2.Mark2  
FROM 
    Table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.column = t2.column
```

step 2 use this view in single query like below.

```
SELECT * from StudentDetails
```

Comment: I want without using join condition. Need Simple select statement or other way

Comment: sorry friend, there is no other way to join table without join query,
but view statement is a predefined join query, its perform well,

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it using `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM StudPersonalinfo S, Mark M
WHERE S.studid=M.studid
```

I would still recommend using `JOIN`. It is the best practice.

Comment: I need totally 3 logics.

Comment: @Perumal: What you mean by 3 logics? You will not get the desired result if you do not show the relation in the query. You can use either `JOIN ... ON..` syntax or `Where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION instead of JOIN. Also can use comma as

1/

```
SELECT * 
    FROM A UNION B 
WHERE condition
```

2/

```
SELECT * 
   FROM A,B 
WHERE condition
```

Answer (score 0):

select empno from emp
intersect
select empno from audit_emp

SELECT *
FROM customers
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
FROM order_details
WHERE customers.customer_id = order_details.customer_id);

Comment: It is good that you contribute, but since this is your first answer here on StackOverflow I do want to inform you that if you provide an answer do use the correct information. The original question mentions the tables **StudPersonalinfo** and **Mark** and both tables have two fields in common, **studid** and **studname**. There is no **customers** or **order_details** table and if using SELECT and only using `StudPersonalinfo.studid = Mark.studid` in the WHERE clause you should use AS clause.

Next time also use a code block markup so that your post/answer is styled and better readable.